# Duplicate Rows using String Split based on "," delimiter and Subtract from qty field

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, split, delimiter

How can I duplicate a row of data based on the number of serial numbers and decrement the quantity
Some rows have no serials

**CURRENT STATE**

| Company | Qty | Product | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | desktop | desk1, desk2, desk 3 |
| b | 2 | server | serv1, serv2 |
| c | 1 | keyboard |  |
| c | 1 | ram | ram1 |
| c | 2 | speakers |  |

**NEW STATE**

| Company | Qty | Product | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | desktop | desk1 |
| a | 1 | desktop | desk2 |
| a | 1 | desktop | desk 3 |
| b | 1 | server | serv1 |
| b | 1 | server | serv2 |
| c | 1 | keyboard |  |
| c | 1 | ram | ram1 |
| c | 2 | speakers |  |

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Try a CROSS APPLY with STRING_SPLIT() ...

```
WITH
indata(Company,Qty,Product,Serial) AS (
          SELECT 'a',3,'desktop','desk1, desk2, desk 3'
UNION ALL SELECT 'b',2,'server','serv1, serv2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',1,'keyboard',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',1,'ram','ram1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'c',2,'speakers',NULL
)
SELECT
  company
, qty
, product
, part.value as serialp
FROM indata
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(serial,',') AS part
UNION ALL SELECT
  company
, qty
, product
, serial AS serialp
FROM indata
WHERE serial IS NULL
ORDER BY company
;

company qty product  serialp
a         3 desktop  desk1
a         3 desktop  desk2
a         3 desktop  desk 3
b         2 server   serv1
b         2 server   serv2
c         1 ram      ram1
c         1 keyboard (NULL) 
c         2 speakers (NULL)
```

Comment: Nice.  It could be even shorter with OUTER APPLY :-) Also, don't forget to adjust the qty. Maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a1e8593e40050ac6892ed1e31d1ba66